# SpamAssassin changes Postfix headers

Tags: postfix, spamassassin

Adding Spamassassin to my Postfix has had an unwarnted effect on my email headers.

We use Postfix with all of the mail routed to a catchall account.  Our virtual_alias_maps file looks something like:

```
@mydomain.com catchall
@mydomain2.com catchall
@mydomain3.com catchall
...
```

If a message is sent to two addresses in our domain, we'll get two messages delivered to the catchall, the first one with headers like:

```
X-Original-To: a1@mydomain.com
Delivered-To: a1@mydomain.com
To: a1@mydomain.com, a2@mydomain.com
```

and the second on with headers like:

```
X-Original-To: a2@mydomain.com
Delivered-To: a2@mydomain.com
To: a1@mydomain.com, a2@mydomain.com
```

This is exactly what we want.  We can look at the X-Original-To or the Delivered-To to know who was the original recipient of the message.  However, when we turn SpamAssassin on, the headers are modified so that both messages look like:

```
X-Original-To: catchall@mydomain.com
Delivered-To: catchall@mydomain.com
To: a1@mydomain.com, a2@mydomain.com
```

and there is absolutely nothing in the message that lets me know which one was for which recipient.

Is there a way to stop SpamAssassin from modifying the headers?  If not, is there another way to preserve the identity of the original recipient?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have configured the `content_filter` to call SA, either in `master.cf` for the one or more services or in `main.cf` for all services. This causes the filter to be called for every mail to be sent, e.g. for every recipient.

You can probably fix this enabling [no_address_mappings](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#no_address_mappings) to you `master.cf`, like so:

```
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o content_filter=spamassassin
  -o receive_override_options=no_address_mappings
```